# React use Prisma plugin, I got the this error. Invalid `prisma.user.findUnique()` invocation:

Tags: reactjs, typescript, mongodb, prisma

In my code, I tried to used this way to running it.

[...nextauth].ts code

```
CredentialsProvider({
      name: 'credentials',
      credentials: {
        email: { label: 'email', type: 'text' },
        password: { label: 'password', type: 'password' }
      },
      async authorize(credentials) {
        if (!credentials?.email  || !credentials?.password) {
          throw new Error('Invalid credentials');
        }

        const user = await prisma.user.findUnique({
          where: {
            email: credentials.email
          }
        });
        if (!user || !user?.hashedPassword) {
          throw new Error('Invalid credentials');
        }

        const isCorrectPassword = await bcrypt.compare(
          credentials.password,
          user.hashedPassword
        );

        if (!isCorrectPassword) {
          throw new Error('Invalid credentials');
        }

        return user;
      }
    })
```

then I got this error information.

```
Invalid `prisma.user.findUnique()` invocation:

{
where: {
email: 'aaabbbccc@gmail.com'
~~~~~
}
}

Unknown arg `email` in where.email for type UserWhereUniqueInput. Did you mean `id`? Available args:
type UserWhereUniqueInput {
id?: String
}
```

In the schema.prisma code, I used this

```
model User {
  id             String    @id @default(auto()) @map("_id") @db.ObjectId
  name           String?
  email          String?   @unique
  emailVerified  DateTime?
  image          String?
  hashedPassword String?
  createdAt      DateTime  @default(now())
}
```

Who knows where has issues? I tried to any way and looks a a lots documents, but still not yet find answer.

still use `npx prisma generate`

but still got error